# Programatically set the width of a DataColumn for use with a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datacolumn

I assign a column programmatically to a DataTable like this:

```
myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);
```

Is there a way to programmatically set the width / size of the column?

Comment: Umm..a datacolumn doesn't have width. do you mean the way it displays on a page...like a grid?

Comment: @Scott I want the column to be more narrow when it is displayed.

Answer (score 8):

```
ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
col1.Width = GridLength.Auto;
ColumnDefinition col2 = new ColumnDefinition();
col2.Width = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star);

grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col2);
```

top pieces will auto size columns, bottom piece you can customize size. look into this site for more detail -- http://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

Comment: Patrick talks about DataGrid, not Grid layout!  what you provided here is about Grid layout.

Comment: For WPF DataGrids use:
`col1.Column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);`

Answer (score 1):

This resizes N-1 columns to "Auto" and column N to "Fill"

```
foreach (var column in dataGrid.Columns)
    column.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;
dataGrid.Columns.Last().Width = DataGridLength.SizeToCells;
```

Comment: +1 however you should get into the habit of placing the body of **foreach** in { }